# How to append version to assembly output file name in .NET Standard 2.0 Library Project

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2022, .net-standard-2.0

I am using VS2022 17.2.3.

In a .NET Standard 2.0 Library Project I wish to change the output assembly file name.

In **Project -> Properties -> Assembly Name**, I see that it is set to `$(MSBuildProjectName)`.

I want to change it to `$(MSBuildProjectName)$(AssemblyVersion)`, but `$(AssemblyVersion)` is not working.

I want to ask if anyone can point to right thing.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check the answer below? If it works you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [MSBuild's Property Evaluation Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/comparing-properties-and-items?view=vs-2022#property-and-item-evaluation-order).

Setting `AssemblyVersion` in the `csproj` file *before setting `AssemblyName`* works fine:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName)$(AssemblyVersion)</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

```
1>CSharpScratchpad -> C:\Projects\CSharpScratchpad\bin\Debug\net6.0\CSharpScratchpad1.0.0.0.dll
```

---

In the comments, you also stated you want to use a wildcard `AssemblyVersion`, like `1.0.*`.

I don't know a good way to access the expanded, final form of the version MSBuild generates internally, so I can only offer a slightly ugly post build copy retrieving the version from the built assembly:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyIdentity"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Exec Command='COPY "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName)%(AssemblyIdentity.Version)$(TargetExt)" /Y' />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

---

In a follow-up comment, you wanted to only append the major.minor version to the file name.

You can create a `System.Version` instance of the assembly version, and call its `ToString(int fieldCount)` method so that it only returns the first 2 segments. This would be the new post build target - I've stored the result in a `MajorMinor` property for <strike>sanity</strike> readability, but you can bash it all into one line if you prefer:

```xml
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyIdentity"/>
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MajorMinor>$([System.Version]::new("%(AssemblyIdentity.Version)").ToString(2))</MajorMinor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command='COPY "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName)$(MajorMinor)$(TargetExt)" /Y' />
</Target>
```

I suggest being able to explain this to your collegues or yourself in a few months. And maybe someone else knows a less convoluted solution for this.

Comment: <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
<AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
<AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName)$(AssemblyVersion)</AssemblyName>

Changing 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.*  does not work.

Comment: @Neha Please don't use the term "does not work" as it does not help identifying your problem. That said, I tried your setup, and your problem apparently is that MSBuild does not expand `AssemblyVersion` and attempts to use the `*` wildcard in the assembly file name. I don't know how to expand `AssemblyVersion` after MSBuild applied its internal logic on it, but I've provided a rather ugly post build rename "solution".

Comment: The PostBuild Idea works.  It gives output like this:    Library1.0.8195.31489.dll

Comment: while I am happy with the output result, I was wondering if i can use only Major and Minor from AssemblyIdentity.Version.  I tried entering AssemblyIdentity.Version.Major but it copies dll file as Library(AssemblyIdentity.Version.Major).dll.

Comment: @Neha I added a way to do that. If you like it.